# Why does adding THREE Geometry to autodesk forge viewer always fail?

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to add (preferably 3D) geometry objects to a forge viewer like they do it [here](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5a361b2b58144b5ed2936ddf). But no matter how I initialize e.g. a THREE.PointCloud, when I want to add it to the viewer scene the following error always occurs:

`THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. THREE.PointCloud`

Could it have to do with the type definitions of the npm forge-viewer package for typescript? I have installed three-js version 0.71.1 like it is explained [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/custom-geometry/)

My test function for drawing a red sphere (just like [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/interactive_examples/example_5/)) looks like this:

```
public async draw(x: number, y: number){
    try{
      const geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 8, 8);
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
      const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);
      sphereMesh.position.set(1, 2, 3);
      if (!this.viewer.overlays.hasScene('custom-scene')) {
        this.viewer.overlays.addScene('custom-scene');
    }
      // add mesh to viewer either with
      this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(sphereMesh, 'custom-scene');
      // or with
      // this.viewer.impl.sceneAfter.add(sphereMesh);
      // ---> both get the same error
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be? The viewer is initialized and a model is loaded.

If you need something from me in order to help me, just tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Great god, `r71` was in **2015** ([release r71](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r71)).

From migration guide you can see that `PointCloud` still exist in `r71` ([Migration `r71` → `r72`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r71--r72)), it is later renamed `Points`.

On previous assumption, I made a working example based on the sphere demo you shared on Codepen: https://codepen.io/trinketmage/pen/rNRKvEM.

Most likely, if you read your error, inside your code you have a variable named `object`, that is not an `Object3D` or an extended class of `Object3D` that you are trying to add to your `Scene`.

- Try checking your variable `object` content and type;
- Make sure it is an `Object3D` or extension of `Object3D` such as `Mesh` or `PointCloud`.

Note: It might be confusing, the THREE.js API has evolved a lot in those years. You might not be able to find documentation related to `r71`. `THREE.Geometry` used to be a thing since `r124` ([Migration `r124` → `r125`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r124--r125)) but it wasn't use for `PointCloud`.

Comment: I wondered if I was the only one who saw `r71` there... But luckily others saw it too...